# Display base64 image with Deno's Oak package

Tags: deno, oak

I've got a base64 encoded image stored in my database, so the start looks like this `data:image/png;base64,iVB..` and I return it from the database at my 'image' endpoint.

I could of course just fetch the content using JavaScript and include the base64 string as `img` source and it would render just fine, but I also want to be able to view the image when I go to the endpoint with my browser. I've tried a combination of different headers but couldn't get it too work.

How do I render a base64 image using Oak?

**EDIT**:

This is the code I ended up using, for anyone interested!

```
const getImage = async (
  { params, response }: { params: { id: string }; response: Response },
) => {
  // Get the image using the ID from the URL
  const image = await imageDatabase.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(params.id) });

  // If there is no image found
  if (!image) {
    response.status = 404;
    return;
  }

  // Return the image to the user
  const semicolonIndex = image.base64!.indexOf(';')
  const colonIndex = image.base64!.indexOf(':')
  const commaIndex = image.base64!.indexOf(',')

  const imageSize = image.base64!.slice(colonIndex + 1, semicolonIndex);
  const imageData = image.base64!.slice(commaIndex + 1);

  response.headers.set('Content-Type', imageSize)
  response.body = base64.toUint8Array(imageData)
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support base64 image content. You should decode it and return with content type.

```js
const images: any = {
  beam: 'data:image/png;base64,<base64-string>',
  google: 'data:image/png;base64,<base64-string>',
}

router.get('/image/:id', ctx => {
  if (ctx.params && ctx.params.id && ctx.params.id in images) {
    const image: string = images[ctx.params.id]
    const colonIdx = image.indexOf(':')
    const semicolonIdx = image.indexOf(';')
    const commaIdx = image.indexOf(',')
    // extract image content type
    ctx.response.headers.set('Content-Type', image.slice(colonIdx + 1, semicolonIdx))
    // encode base64
    ctx.response.body = base64.toUint8Array(image.slice(commaIdx + 1))
  }
})
```

To find full code, see [code on github](https://github.com/XDean/StackOverflow/blob/master/src/main/deno/Q66697683.ts)

Or you can run my sample directly

```sh
deno run -A https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XDean/StackOverflow/master/src/main/deno/Q66697683.ts
```